# Setter method not generated for JAX B object of type list

Tags: jaxb

Setter method is not generated when i create JAX classes from XSD,for maxOccurs=unbounded type. I need to manually add setter method for `DetailType` .Is this the right approach since i need to populate DetailType inside the root element

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "WPExchangeRate")
public class WPExchangeRate {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    protected HeaderType header;
    @XmlElement(name = "Detail", required = true)
    protected List<DetailType> detail;
    @XmlElement(name = "Trailer")
    protected TrailerType trailer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Just do `getDetail().add(myDetail)`.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Maven**:
In your `pom.xml` add to the plugin's `<configuration>`:

```
<args>
    <arg>-Xsetters</arg>
</args>
```

If you want to configure generation method: `-Xsetters-mode=accessor` or `-Xsetters-mode=direct`.

**If you are generating from command line**:
Add `-Xsetters` to the command (same for `-Xsetters-mode`).